# Why does True != True != True evaluate to False

Tags: python

In Python, `True != True` is `False`, and `False != True` should be `True`. However, shouldn't the result of the evaluation then be `True`, as well?

Comment: I executed this: print (True != True) print (False != True).And the output I got is False True. I dont get what exactly is your doubt here.

Comment: The doubt comes from thinking that the conditions are evaluated sequentially and cumulatively, like an arithmetic operation. Instead, this is actually a chain of single, simultaneous checks (chained by an `and` operation).

Comment: See the [documentation for comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Comment: Why is this tagged `perl`?

Comment: @Sobrique I was wondering about that, myself, so I submitted an edit to have this tag removed. That edit just got accepted, so now that tag is removed

Answer (score 7):

This is because the two checks are preformed independently. `True != True != True` is equivalent to `True != True and True != True`, which evaluates to `False`, as neither of the operands evaluates to `True` (in fact, it doesn't even evaluate the second `True != True` comparison, due to short-circuiting).

The relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).